# how to test a pop order is legal or not?

Tags: algorithm

Given two unique number sequences: `push order of stack` and `pop order of stack`, numbers in `push order` are in ascending sort order, now ask the `pop order` is legal or not ?

For example, the `push order` is 1 2 3 4 5, so 4 5 3 2 1 is a legal pop order, because we can push and pop like this:

`push 1, push 2, push 3, push 4, pop, push 5, pop, pop, pop, pop`

so pop order: 4 5 3 2 1 is legal, and 4 3 5 1 2 is not a legal pop order.

Comment: @user2246674, it's not necessary, pop means getting and removing the top element of the stack, we Can't specify a number to be poped.

Comment: Ah, yes, that there is *any* such ordering ..

Comment: What was your question??

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about computer science, not programs.


Comment: From what I can understand, it seems to be a tautology.  What's to test?

Comment: @bmargulies It's about algorithms. Saying it's "about computer science" probably doesn't really help too much for someone that doesn't know about the [cs.se] site (if this is what you meant). I believe these types of questions are on topic for [programmers.se], [cs.se] and [so], but [so] *definitely* has the most of these types of questions (and I know since these are my favourite type of questions). Though I can't really argue with you had you wanted to say the question "must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your push sequence is in ascending order, then when you see a number `N` in your pop queue, then
all numbers that is 1) below `N` and 2) not yet popped, must be popped in descending order.

For example, 4 3 5 1 2 is not a valid order, since when we see '4' popped, than all numbers
smaller than '4' but not yet popped before must be popped in descending order.  However, popping '1' first and then '2' violates this property.

Comment: It seems that your solution by `maintaining the maximum and minimum numbers` is not working for sequence `1, 2, 3, 5, 4`..

Comment: What's the time complexity? O(n^2)?

Comment: @Dukeling: A naive check would be O(n^2), but the checking could be done in O(n) with a stack (one example would be your solution: actually construct a stack so you can know which element is already popped).

Answer (score 4):

One option is to actually construct the stack:

For each number `X` in the pop order:

- If this number is not the same as the top of the stack (or the stack is empty), push numbers from the push order until you pushed `X`. If you pushed all numbers and didn't find `X`, there's no way to get the pop order.
- Pop `X`

Note that this actually doesn't require that the push order is ascending.

You can take advantage of the ordering to optimize the above slightly (to fail earlier) by failing if `X` is smaller than the top of the stack.

Since you only push each element at most once, the above is linear time (which you can't do better than) and linear space.

**Example:**

```
Push: 1 2 3 4 5  
Pop: 4 5 3 2 1

Processing: 4
    Stack empty -> push until 4 is on the top of the stack.
    Stack: 1 2 3 4
    Pop 4
    Stack: 1 2 3

Processing: 5
    3 != 5 -> push until 5 is on the top of the stack.
    Stack: 1 2 3 5
    Pop 5
    Stack: 1 2 3

Processing: 3
    Pop 3
    Stack: 1 2

Processing: 2
    Pop 2
    Stack: 1

Processing: 1
    Pop 1
    Stack: 

Done.
```

Answer (score 2):

**Assumption:** The push order and the pop order contains exactly the same numbers. If this is not a valid assumption, it can be validated using a hash-set (or hash-map with counts if there can be duplicates) in linear time, although this would compromise the O(1) space complexity.

**Idea:** Every element in the pop order must either be less than the element before it, or more than the maximum so far, otherwise the pop order is not valid.

This can be checked in O(n) time and O(1) space by just keeping track of the maximum.

**Why this works:**

The push order is in ascending order, thus, regardless of when you pop elements:

1. The stack will always be ascending order as well and
2. The next item in the push order will always be larger than the largest element seen on the stack.

So there are two options:

- Two pop operations in a row - in this case the second element will be smaller
- Two pop operations with one or more push operations in between - in this case the second element will be larger than the maximum (following from 2.)

**Examples:**

`4 5 3 2 1` is valid since 5 > max (4), 3 < 5, 2 < 3 and 1 < 2.

`4 3 5 1 2` is not valid since 2 > 1 but 2 < max (5).

`1 2 3 5 4` is valid since 2 > max (1), 3 > max (2), 5 > max (3) and 4 < 5.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

```
i: from 1 to n
j: from 1 to n, used to traverse the sequence seq[1...n]
stack: empty at the beginning
while i <= n || j <= n
    IF stack is empty,
        push i into stack, i plus 1;
    ELSE IF the top of stack is equal to seq[j]
        pop from stack, j plus 1;
    ELSE IF the top of stack is larger than seq[j]
        illegal sequence! Stop here!
    ELSE 
        push i into stack, i plus 1;
legal sequence if the stack is empty!
```

**Example 1: {1, 2, 4, 3}, legal sequence**

```
In the beginning, i = 1, j = 1, and stack is empty.

1. stack is empty: 
   stack = {1}, i = 2, j = 1.

2. top of stack 1 is equal to seq[j] = 1: 
   stack = {}, i = 2, j = 2.

3. stack is empty: 
   stack = {2}, i = 3, j = 2.

4. top of stack 2 is equal to seq[j] = 2: 
   stack = {}, i = 3, j = 3.

5. stack is empty: 
   stack = {3}, i = 4, j = 3.

6. top of stack 3 is smaller than seq[j] = 4: 
   stack = {3, 4}, i = 5, j = 3.

7. top of stack 4 is equal to seq[j] = 4: 
   stack = {3}, i = 5, j = 4.

8. top of stack 3 is equal to seq[j] = 3:
   stack = {}, i = 5, j = 5.
```

**Example 2: {1, 4, 2, 3}, illegal sequence**

```
In the beginning, i = 1, j = 1, and stack is empty.

1. stack is empty: 
   stack = {1}, i = 2, j = 1.

2. top of stack 1 is equal to seq[j] = 1: 
   stack = {}, i = 2, j = 2.

3. stack is empty: 
   stack = {2}, i = 3, j = 2.

4. top of stack 2 is smaller than seq[j] = 4: 
   stack = {2, 3}, i = 4, j = 2.

5. top of stack 3 is smaller than seq[j] = 4: 
   stack = {2, 3, 4}, i = 5, j = 2.

6. top of stack 4 is equal to seq[j] = 4: 
   stack = {2, 3}, i = 5, j = 3.

7. top of stack 3 is larger than seq[j] = 2: 
   illegal sequence, stop here.
```

I'm trying my best to explain my idea, hope that I've made things clear.

Comment: you simulate the `push` and `pop` order, I did not understand your idea, sorry. And there is a small bug in your code: u can't use `pop()` in 'if', should use `peek()` or other similar method.

Comment: @hiway Sorry, I wanted to edit my answer but didn't get time. Now I use words and examples for explaining my idea. You may check it now:)